# RefinementWebPart - UseDefaultConfiguration property

Tags: search, object-model

I'm trying to create a filter dynamically through code, and for that I need to set the property **UseDefaultConfiguration** to false.

However, just this simple thing below causes the webpart to "hang" on the page, with the message "Refresh the page to see the latest changes."

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    UseDefaultConfiguration = false;
    base.CreateChildControls();
}
```

I can refresh as long as I want, but nothing happens. Did I put this first line in a wrong place or something? How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance,
Igor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always seem to get this message while the page is in edit mode, even after refreshing as it suggests. Have you tried stopping editing and going back to the display mode for the page?

Comment: Of course!
Saving, refreshing, restarting browser, viewing in different browser, restarting machine, everything..

It's only the webpart that seems to stay stuck in the edit mode.

Comment: It was just a thought. Have you tried setting the property earlier in the page lifecycle? E.g. override OnInit(xxx) ?